# Ajuda para transformar um for each ( de um file_get_contents php ) em Json Encode

Tags: php, api, parser, php-domdocument, php-domxpath

to realizando um file_get_contents php em um site, ai mostra todos os times deste site,
no loop do for each ele me mostra todos os time ( que estão entre as tags do file ), porém queria transformar todos esses times em Json encode ( transformar em API ).

Por causa do file_get_contents php não consigo transformar esses dados em array para ser exibido em Json Encode, tentei bastante coisa e não tive um resultado positivo, irei deixar meu código, se alguém conseguir isto.

única coisa que tive resultado foi de uma resposta ( um time ), no caso queria todos os times.

```html
<?php
echo "[";
// URL DO SITE
$url = ' url do site';

// PEGANDO TODO CONTEUDO
$dadosSite = file_get_contents($url);

$var1 = explode('<h4><b>',$dadosSite);

//possivel filtro


foreach( $var1 as $idArray => $array){

if($i)
{

 $horajogo = explode('</b></h4>',$array);

//=======> time um
  // filtrar o que voce quer 
  $timeum = explode('width="25" height="25">',$array);
  // filtrar ate onde voce quer
  $timeum = explode('</div>',$timeum[1]);
 
  
$cliente1 = array(
    'codigo'   => $timeum[0],
);
}
 
$i++;
}



echo json_encode($cliente1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);



?>
```

queria fazer algo do tipo, porem que aparece TODOS os times.

```html
[{
    "camp": "Campeonato Brasileiro",
    "hrs": "22:00",
    "time": "Arsenal",
    "img": "https://futebolnatv.com.br/static/times/33a929f9e1e26c8a52e0b2c1bee44d6e.png",
    "gol": "1",
    "goldois": "5",
    "timedois": "Liverpool",
    "imgdois": "https://futebolnatv.com.br/static/times/abe768c15fc134e24d933eef88e5d438.png",
    "tempo": "Ao vivo PENALTIS",
    "trans": "SPORTV(-RS), PREMIERE FC"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exemplo abaixo eu estou usando DOMXPath para navegar, supondo, pelo que vi do conteúdo do HTML, que somente uma tabela exista nesta página.

Você precisa melhorar de acordo com detalhes de sua necessidade, mas neste exemplo estou pegando cada coluna de cada linha e gerando uma entrada em uma linha da array (o horário e o jogo).

Veja que a questão que você levantou não tem a ver com a forma que está lendo os dados, usando file_get_contents, e sim com a forma de fazer o parser desta fonte de dados.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/';

// PEGANDO TODO CONTEUDO
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

libxml_clear_errors(); //remove erros de html quebrado

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$table = $xpath->query('//table')->item(0);
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

$dados=[];
foreach($rows as $row)
  {
    $linha = [];
    $jogo = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $hora = $row->getElementsByTagName('th');
    $linha['hora'] = $hora[0]->nodeValue;
    $linha['jogo'] = $jogo[0]->nodeValue;
        
    $dados[] = $linha;
  }

  print_r(json_encode($dados));
```

Comment: realmente do seu jeito funcionou, vou procurar informações na internet para entender sobre esse DOMXPath, Muito obrigado

Comment: Que ótimo, como é novo na comunidade vou orientar como proceder agora, se puder, marque minha resposta como aceita, assim minha pontuação aumenta e me permite ter acesso a mais ferramentas do stackoverflow para contribuir com a plataforma

Comment: pronto, poderia me indicar algum vídeo referente a este caso ? obrigado

Comment: Obrigado. QUanto ao vídeo, infelizmente não conheço nenhum, mas estou criando conteúdo de capacitação em meu canal, posso anotar como um conteúdo pendente sobre DOM com PHP mas não posso te garantir que faria isso esta semana, mais provável para daqui uns 15 dias. Me segue no Youtube que recebe daí o aviso do vídeo quando disponibilizado

Comment: mazer dev  ? segui seu canal

Comment: Isso, mas acho que a pesquisa no Youtube me encontra pelo meu nome Ademir Mazer Junior